# extract different number in two array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Here i come with to extract different number in two array in java .different number are to be store in third list of array i am new to java could some one guide me in right Direction 
which i tried upto now??

```
int[] list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int[] list1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int [] list2 =null;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list1.length; j++)
    {
        if(list[i]!=list1[j])
        {
            System.out.println(list2[]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dono how to store That different Value in Third list of Array???

Comment: `System.out.println(list2[])` will not even compile...

Comment: You need to, first, *create the array* `list2 = new int[size]` and then assign to it `list2[position] = number`

Comment: Y downwote for this question i am newbie so only am approaching here wt is the wrong??

Comment: Because you are not telling us which is the error, only that "I want the code to do X"... it is not a question, but a request for code which is frowned upon.

Comment: @user3331535 We're sorry. Downvote does not mean we won't help you. But state that you may have find answer elseware.

Comment: fine i will try at my level best so i cant further so only i came here?? is there any wrong in this??

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/253868-how-do-i-find-the-difference-of-arrays/ Calm dow , see this article

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int[] list1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int [10] list2 =null;
boolean flag=false;
int k=0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < list1.length; j++)
{
    if(list[i]!=list1[j])
    {
        flag=false;
    }
    else
    {
        flag=true;
    }
    if(flag==true)
    {
        list2[k]=list[i];
        k++;
    }
}
}
```

Now I am pretty sure about answer.

Comment: I updated answer. I like this website. Got many suggestions and improved my mistakes.

Comment: Besides , OP's logic is wrong. If you read the logic cleary , you'll see that this will not output like op want.

Comment: @Poomrokc .Again Updated. Finally This Will Work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that in java you need to specify the size of the array.
What you can do :

```
int[] list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int[] list1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int size = list1.length;
boolean found = false;
int[] list2=new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
        if(list[i]==list1[i])
        {
            found = true;
        }
     }
     if(found)
        found = false;
     else
        list2[i]=list1[i];
}
System.print.out("List2={");
for(int k = 0;  k < list2.length; k++){
    if(list2[k] != 0)
       System.print.out(list2[k] + ", ");
}
System.print.out("}");
```

(c.f. : [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html))

Comment: Or just pick the longest array.

Comment: i want ouput as like list2={8,9,10} am noting this output